# disabling the seat images in bus seat layout

Tags: javascript, node.js

```
if(www[15] != "false") {
  var seatavailablepng="Public2/images/empty-seat.png";
} else {  
   if(yyy[15] != "false") { 
     varseatavailablepng="Public2/images/ladies-seat.png";
   } else { 
      var seatavailablepng="Public2/images/reserved-seat.png";
   }
}   
  sts +=  '<td align="right" id="three" name="seat[]" onclick=myfuncset("'+vvv[15]+'",'+fare[15]+') ><a href="#" id="'+vvv[15]+'"><img src='+seatavailablepng+' alt="" id='+seatestatus+'/></a></td>';
```

Here if www[15]  is false, then the onclick should not work, means it should not click (disable).

Comment: Read the SO post how to format and ask question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add condition before adding into `sts` value. Based on that condition remove the clickable part from your code. Also found one problem is `seatavailablepng` is created everytime as a local variable. Create global variable `seatavailablepng` and update it like below.

```
var seatavailablepng = ""; //keep default url image
if(www[15] != "false") {
  seatavailablepng="Public2/images/empty-seat.png";
} else {  
   if(yyy[15] != "false") { 
      seatavailablepng="Public2/images/ladies-seat.png";
   } else { 
      var seatavailablepng="Public2/images/reserved-seat.png";
   }
}
if(www[15] == "false") {
    sts +=  '<td align="right" id="three" name="seat[]"><img src='+seatavailablepng+' alt="" id='+seatestatus+'/></td>';
} else {
    sts +=  '<td align="right" id="three" name="seat[]" onclick=myfuncset("'+vvv[15]+'",'+fare[15]+') ><a href="#" id="'+vvv[15]+'"><img src='+seatavailablepng+' alt="" id='+seatestatus+'/></a></td>';
}
```